# How to encode JSON embedded within JSON

Tags: json

I have a JSON string and one of the fields is a text field. This text field can contain text that a user enters in the UI and if the text they enter is JSON text, perhaps to illustrate some coding, I need to encode their text so that it does not get interpreted as JSON within the actual JSON structure sent to the server.

When the JSON structure is received by the server and gets decoded, I need to make sure the embedded JSON gets decoded as text, which ends up looking like JSON in the UI.

In effect, how do you escape an embedded JSON string?

Comment: What platform? For most, if not all, JSON generators, if you give it a string it will take care of the encoding/decoding and there's no risk of it erroneously decoding a JSON string you give it as a value.

Comment: I'm using Android and Java. I am also manually generating the json string in code. I do use Gson for some encoding and decoding but in this case, I am doing it manually with Gson.

Comment: A string is a string... Decoding your "outer JSON" won't automatically decode the "inner JSON", as the parser does not know what's the content of the string. There is nothing you have to do.

Comment: Felix: My inner string is a json string that looks exactly like any normal json string and when you embed it, it will get interpreted as json. I want it interpreted as text and not as json.

Comment: @AndroidDev In that case just escape quotation marks like you would in any other string value. That's all. However, rolling your own JSON is usually neither a great idea nor remotely necessary unless your use case is very specific and very, very limited in scope.

Comment: As I said, if you do it properly, you don't have to do anything. If it gets interpreted, then you inner JSON is not a string. So maybe you have `{"foo": [1,2,3]}` instead of `{"foo": "[1,2,3]"}`. If it is a string, i.e. a string inside JSON, then you don't have to worry. A JSON parser does not interpret strings as JSON, otherwise something like `{"foo": "-bar"}` would throw an error. Don't build your JSON manually, always use an encoder.

Comment: Thanks, I'll stick with the parser. It turns out that all you really need to be concerned about is escaping the quotation marks. Using the parser though does escape other characters as well such as apostrophes, so it is safer to use the parser.

Comment: @AndroidDev, you need to escape more than just quotation marks, control characters (including newlines) also need to be escaped, as per the JSON spec. Also if the JSON will be executed as javascript U+2028 and U+2029 need to be escaped as well (if they occur)

Answer (score 15):

I'm doing something similar, just with XML instead of JSON: On receiving malformed or otherwise non-processable data the server returns an error-structure containing some information and the original data. To prevent the client from parsing the corrupt data again it's **base64 encoded** on the server.

So instead of sending

```
{
  title : "My sample code",
  payload : "{ \"foo\" : \"bar\" }"
}
```

consider sending

```
{
  title : "My encoded sample code",
  payload : "eyAiZm9vIiA6ICJiYXIiIH0="
}
```

Comment: What is interesting is that Chrome console would produce error, if you try to run the following: `JSON.parse('{"title":"My sample code","payload":"{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"}');`

> VM1725:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token f in JSON at position 39
>    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
>    at <anonymous>:1:6

Comment: @pilat Not really. It's just a misunderstanding of how the escaping works. Try `JSON.parse('{"title":"My sample code","payload":"{\\"foo\\":\\"bar\\"}"}');`. You're already within a String, so you'll have to escape the backslashes as well.